# Auto Layout Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, ios-autolayout

I'm using this visual format layout `"V:[v0]-16-|"` in:

```
self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-16-|", views: imageView)
```

and the helper method is the following:

```
func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
```

but what I want in reality is something like "V:[v0]+16+|", I want the right constraint to go beyond the `UIScreen`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try to remove the last pipe:
`V:|-16-[v0]-16`

Comment: @TalCohen I changed the constraints a bit for what I really want

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: "V:[v0]-16-|" is what I have, but I want something like "V:[v0]+16+|", and it didn't worked

Comment: What about `"V:[v0]-(-16)-|"` ?

Comment: @JamesP awesome! put that in the answers

Comment: People still use it? Doesn't it introduces bugs with its string type. Why not anchors...

Comment: @AmberK I use VFL all the time and don't run into bugs. It can be far more concise than anchors. I cringe when I see a tens of lines of anchor code that could be written in 2 lines with VFL.

Comment: @JamesP Nice, but you can get typos..right? What I do is writing some extensions predefined or you can use some autolayout library that is strongly typed.

Comment: Yeah you can get typos, but then you'll get a handy error that tells you why. I don't bother with a library, just a mix of VFL and anchors for edge cases. Works for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative margin to position the view past the edge of the parent. Just put the constant in brackets like this:

```
self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-(-16)-|", views: imageView)
```